# Automapper chain / nested object mapping throw exception

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, automapper

I am using AutoMapper version 10.1.1 in .NET CORE 5 project. I have nested object that I need map but unable to do so and getting following exception although I can get data mapped for first child which in my case 'Enforcements' but cannot access to child of child Object 'Contraventions'

[image]

### Class at Level 0

```
 public class SiteContraventionDataView
{
    public int SiteId { get; set; }

    public string SiteName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<EnforcementDataView> Enforcements { get; set; }

}
```

### Child Class at level 1

```
public class EnforcementDataView
{
    public int EnforcementId { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ContraventionDataView> Contraventions { get; set; }
}
```

I am getting error when I try to set source for 'Contraventions' from above child class. I am trying to lambda expression to get Contravention object reference

```
 .ForMember(dataView => dataView.Enforcements.Select(x=>x.Contraventions), opt => opt.MapFrom(dataModel => GetContraventions(dataModel.Enforcements.ToList())))
```

### AutoMapping class

```
public class SiteContraventionsProfile : Profile
{
    public SiteContraventionsProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Site, SiteContraventionDataView>()
            .ForMember(dataView => dataView.SiteId, opt => opt.MapFrom(dataModel => dataModel.SiteId))
            .ForMember(dataView => dataView.SiteName, opt => opt.MapFrom(dataModel => dataModel.SiteName))
            .ForMember(dataView => dataView.Enforcements, opt => opt.MapFrom(dataModel => dataModel.Enforcements))
            .ForMember(dataView => dataView.Enforcements.Select(x=>x.Contraventions), opt => opt.MapFrom(dataModel => GetContraventions(dataModel.Enforcements.ToList())))
            ;

       
    }

    private List<Contravention> GetContraventions(List<Enforcement> enforcements)
    {
        List<Contravention> contraventions = new List<Contravention>();

        if (enforcements.Any())
        {
            var t1 = enforcements.Select(x => x.EnforcementContraventions);
        }
        
        return contraventions;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add mappings for `Enforcement` and `Contravention`:

```
CreateMap<Enforcement, EnforcementDataView>();
CreateMap<Contravention, ContraventionDataView>();
CreateMap<Site, SiteContraventionDataView>();
```